# LazyColumn and ViewModel Updating, but UI does not. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, viewmodel

I have a list that I'm passing into a LazyColumn. The list is updated from ViewModel values that are entered in a TextField, and these values are collected as a flow in my Composable and that is where the LazyColumn itself is updated.

From log files, the Composable with the LazyColumn is redrawn whenever the TextField is changed, and the LazyColumn's list is updated, as is Composable it uses to draw the list. However, nothing changes in the UI. What am I missing?

Textfield:

```
onValueChange = {
if (it.length <= 9 && it.length > 0) {
       if (moneyType == "income") { incomeViewModel.updateIncome(stringToLong(it)) }
       if (moneyType == "assets") { incomeViewModel.updateAssets(stringToLong(it)) }
            }
        },
```

Ui Composable:

```
val incomeUiState by incomeViewModel.incomeUiState.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
val formulas = Formulas(incomeUiState.income, incomeUiState.assets)
val stringLists = StringLists(formulas)

Column (modifier = Modifier
    .height(height.dp)) {
    Text(context.getString(R.string.income_analysis, formulas.comparedIncomeString, formulas.comparedAssetsString), fontSize = 20.sp)
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))
    Text(context.getString(R.string.jeff_and_you), fontSize = 20.sp, fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold)

    Comparisons(stringLists.list)
}
```

LazyColumn:

```
@Composable
fun Comparisons(comparisonString: List<StringDataClass>) {
LazyColumn {
    items(comparisonString) { ourString ->
        ComparisonLayout(ourString)
    }
}
```

}

Comment: are you updating your value using incomeUiState.value.income = something ?

Comment: I would recommend that you move all logic and variables (`formulas`, `stringLists`) to the ViewModel and leave only the final state in the UI. Declaring variables and creating objects in the scope of a composable function without using `remember{}` can lead to unexpected behavior.